# difference in data between JavaScript & equivalent c#

Tags: c#, javascript

I currently have a working JavaScript that I'm trying to re-make in c#.  The JavaScript creates an XML document from form-entry on an HTML page:

```
var httpOb = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
httpOb.Open("POST", "http://IP_ADDRESS:1111/command.xml", false);
httpOb.send(usg);
```

"usg" is built from and XML ID using form inputs as the element values.

In c# I'm trying to accomplish a technically identical function, but the code gives me a timeout error (as though the target isn't responding) at GetRequestStream():

```
    string xmlString = "<USG COMMAND=\"USER_ADD\" MAC_ADDR=\"14DAE93E0BD8\"><USER_NAME>test1</USER_NAME><PASSWORD ENCRYPT=\"FALSE\"></PASSWORD><IP_TYPE></IP_TYPE><EXPIRY_TIME UNITS=\"SECONDS\"></EXPIRY_TIME><ROOM_NUMBER></ROOM_NUMBER><PAYMENT_METHOD>ROOM_OPEN</PAYMENT_METHOD><CONFIRMATION></CONFIRMATION><PAYMENT></PAYMENT></USG>";
string url = "http://12.23.250.2:1111/usg/command.xml";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
TextBox1.Text = doc.InnerXml;

HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = null;//Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebRequest class.
HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = null;//Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebResponse class
httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
byte[] bytes;
    bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(doc.InnerXml);
    //Set HttpWebRequest properties
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

    using (Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        //Writes a sequence of bytes to the current stream 
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();//Close stream
    }
```

Why is the JavaScript working flawlessly, but not the c#?  What are the differences between these methods that might cause the failure?  I'd just use the JavaScript, but it's dependent upon an ActiveX Control and is done on the Client Side.  I need to accomplish this POST from the server side.

Please help, this is driving me crazy!
Bradley

Comment: Your C# code seems ok..
At which line you are getting timeout?

Comment: are you able to reach the URL from the server ?

Comment: Line 29:         using (Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())

Comment: It says: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [IP_REDACTED]:1111

Comment: The JavaScript works perfectly, if I can figure out how to replicate the "action" being performed by it in c# - it should work... very frustrating.

Comment: AMOS : yes I can actually pull up the "command.xml" file on the server by manually typing the IP.  You probably won't be able to (as your Global IP must be present in the Gateway Device as an authorized XML Server).  But to answer your question, yes, I can open it manually and see it.  When It's opened manually it just shows an "error" as it expects to be POSTED to by an outside script with the "XML Command", to which it responds "ok" or "error".